# JabRef multi-author glitches?

Tags: bibtex, jabref

I'm using JabRef to do all my referencing, but sometimes the `.bib` files I download gives weird author outputs.

For example, I want the author field to look like (as appeared in Google Books):

> Monegon, Ltd, F.A. Costello, Inc, Bird Engineering-Research Associates, United States. National Aeronautics and Space Administration

Instead I get:

> Monegon, L.; F.A. Costello, I.; Associates, B. E.-R.; Aeronautics, U. S. N. & Administration, S.

I understand that these aren't conventional authors, but is there a way to stop JabRef from formatting the author field?

Thanks!

Comment: Double brace your author entries.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use extra braces around the part of the names which should not be enshortened.

It should look like this:

```
@ARTICLE{Aalst2003,
author = {{Wil .M.P.} {van der Aalst} and {Arthur. H. M.} {ter Hofstede} and
B. Kiepuszewski and {A. P.} Barros},
title = {Workflow Patterns},
journal = {Distributed and Parallel Databases},
year = {2003},
volume = {3},
pages = {S. 5-51},
month = jul,
lastchecked = {07.03.2012},
owner = {paschke},
timestamp = {2012.03.07},
url = {http://www.workflowpatterns.com/documentation/documents/wfs-pat-2002.pdf}
}
```